# Generating an arbitrarily long sequence with decreasing Kolmogorov complexity of terms

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, computational-complexity, algorithmic-randomness

Is there an algorithm which, given a string $s$, generates a  sequence of $|s|$ strings, such that it can be proven in some axiomatic system $S$,  that the Kolmogorov complexity of each successive term is smaller than the preceeding one?

We  further impose a constraint that the terms of the strings themselves, do not decrease  in length monotonically.

Comment: That would allow you to produce an $x_n$ with $K(x_n)>n$, say, on input $n$, which only needs $\log n$ bits to encode, and this plainly contradicts the definition of Kolmogorov complexity.

Comment: Such a sequence should in fact have (provably) $K(x_n) <n + c $ for some additive const c based upon the choice of description language and the algorithm. Am I missing something?

Comment: Given $n$, I compute the $n$ numbers your hypothetical algorithm produces and then take the one with the largest complexity and call it $x_n$.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @ChristianRemling  I see your point now, please see the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is such an algorithm.

Let $x_n$ be the first string outputted on input $$s=00\cdots 0=0^n.$$
Then $x_n$ has complexity at most $\log_2 n+C$ since I just described it in terms of $n$.
On the other hand, the complexity is at least $n$ by assumption...

which is a contradiction.